# Many to Many or One to Many Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have the following two models in Django. One is basically an extension of the base Django user class and the other is a company model. I want to say that a user can belong to one or more companies and that a company can also have one or more contacts = "Users". Would this be a correct setup? How should I represent the tie between user and company?

User Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Company model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    sales_rep = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_sales", default="")
    csr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_csr", default="")

class CompanyContact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, is there a reason to extend the `User` model? The default model already includes a `first_name` and `last_name` field, so you don't need an additional model just for that data. Similarly, you don't really need `CompanyContact` because the `User` model also contains `email` and `name` (again, through `first_name` and `last_name`) fields.

You can add in your contacts as a `ManyToManyField`. If you want to use the custom `Profile` model instead of `User`, just replace `User` (in the `ManyToManyField`) with `Profile`.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
    sales_rep = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_sales", default="")
    csr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_csr", default="")
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(User) # or Profile
```

This allows each company to have *many* contacts and each user to be a contact of *many* companies – thus many-to-many.

---

Now, if you wanted extra data to describe the many-to-many relationship, [you can have another model for that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). For example, you may want to keep a record if the contact is still active or what their role is. So, you may have a `CompanyContact` model that is similar to:

```
class CompanyContact(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) # or Profile
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Then, declare the `ManyToManyField` relationship to use this new model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="CompanyContact")
    # or contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, through="CompanyContact")
```

Comment: Awesome! I wanted to add name and email to company contact incase a "contact" doesn't have a profile. An admin would be able to enter their own manual contacts for that company while also having the ability to link an actual user as company contact

Comment: Also, Profile will contain more info then just first_name and last_name. In the future it may contain: theme, birthday, access rules.

Comment: @SamMunroe It may get a bit unwieldy to duplicate the email/name in the contact. Instead, I suggest the following: keep the ManyToMany relationship between `User` and `Company` through `CompanyContact`, and then always create a `User` when adding a contact. The `Profile` is separate and contains additional information, but not required to be a contact.